# Labels with tags inside prototype cells not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I am trying to create a checklist for part of an application that I am currently building, and I am having trouble using `viewWithTag:` to update the text on my prototype cells. Everything else in the app is working correctly, and I can click on the cells that are being created.

The two methods that require viewWithTag to be used are:

```
- (void)configureCheckmarkForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell withChecklistItem:(OTChecklistItem *)item {
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];

    if (item.checked) {
        label.text = @"√";
    } else {
        label.text = @"";
    }

    label.textColor = self.view.tintColor; }
```

and

```
- (void)configureTextForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell withChecklistItem:(OTChecklistItem *)item
{
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
    label.text = item.itemName;
}
```

These methods are being called by:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Get a new or recycled cell
    UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OTChecklistTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *items = [[OTChecklistStore sharedStore] allItems];
    OTChecklistItem *item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self configureTextForCell:cell withChecklistItem:item];
    [self configureCheckmarkForCell:cell withChecklistItem:item];

    return cell;
}
```

Here are some screenshots from my storyboard that show that my connections and tags should be correct.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: your save method is empty!! - (void)save:(id)sender
{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                                                      completion:nil];
} only dismisses the view!!

Comment: The object has already been created, so I had no need to do anything other than dismiss the view. After you create a new object from within the table, you can try clicking on the cell, and the data you saved will show in the detailViewController.

Comment: Don't post a ink to your project. Update your question with the relevant details/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. And It worked:

> The identifier used to deque the cell from the cellForRow method is
>   defferent than the one set in the interface builder. check it out.

**Change:**

```
UITableViewCell *cell =
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OTChecklistTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

**To:**

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OTPlansTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: This worked for you? I tried to change the cellIdentifier within to OTChecklistTableViewCell and it is still not working.

Comment: Did you tried exctly my suggestion?! why you changed that indentifier in interface builder? try the suggested solution first. then do what you want. becuase you also have this un-neccessary line in your code: [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
           forCellReuseIdentifier:@"OTChecklistTableViewCell"];

Comment: I would like to say that work code is well formed and structured.